# Mal funcionamiento de un botón simple

Tags: javascript, html

¿Dónde falla el funcionamiento del boton "Cambiar"?

Consiste en un archivo HTML que tiene enlazado un archivo JS en el mismo directorio.

"Cambiar" deberia mostrar un bloque de código HTML que está oculto.

```js
function show_PassChange(){
 var x=document.getElementById("PassChange");
 if(x.style.display=='inline'){x.style.display:'none';}
 else{x.style.display:'none'}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="prueba.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
   </head>
   <body>
      <button onclick="show_PassChange();">Cambiar</button> 
      <div id="PassChange">
         <ul style="display:none;"> <label>Contrasenia:</label> <input type=password> <label>Confirmar contrasenia:</label> <input type=password> </ul>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `x.style.display:'none';` no es dos punto, se usa el sugno de igual (`=`). ``x.style.display='none';``

Comment: Me sirvio , muchas gracias!!

Comment: tambien fijate en el if, si el if se cumple haces lo mismo tanto en el if como en el else, mejor elimina el if y el else y solo deja `x.style.display='none';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que encuentro es que estás utilizando `:` en vez de `=` para asignar el valor de la propiedad display en ambos casos, al parecer estás confundiendo la forma como se asignan dichos valores en CSS y en JavaScript.

```js
function show_PassChange(){
 var x=document.getElementById("PassChange");
 if(x.style.display=='inline'){x.style.display ='none';}
 else{x.style.display ='none'}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="prueba.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
   </head>
   <body>
      <button onclick="show_PassChange();">Cambiar</button> 
      <div id="PassChange">
         <ul> <label>Contrasenia:</label> <input type=password> <label>Confirmar contrasenia:</label> <input type=password> </ul>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

tu codigo tienene alguanas fallas:

- el elemento display:'none' debes colocarlo en la etiqueta que tiene el mismo id que usaras en el JS, en tu codigo no es asi
- Cambie el atributo .style.display ='none'; por .style.display ='block';

finalmente quedaria así:

```js
function show_PassChange(){
 var x=document.getElementById("PassChange");
 if(x.style.display=='inline'){
    x.style.display = 'block';
  }
 else{
    x.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="prueba.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
   </head>
   <body>
      <button onclick="show_PassChange();">Cambiar</button> 
      <div id="PassChange" style="display:none;">
         <ul > <label>Contrasenia:</label> <input type=password> <label>Confirmar contrasenia:</label> <input type=password> </ul>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ahi me ha funcionado , muchas gracias!!

Comment: Tu respuesta se acopla a lo que el OP pidio, de seguro fue un error de dedo o de click :-) saludos.